# Taxonomies and subtaxonomies relations

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I am struggling with how to relate taxonomies and subtaxonomies in wordpress.
I have one custom taxonomy (Courses) and a subtaxonomy (Recipes) from Courses. I also have another taxonomy (Country) and a subtaxonomy (Cusine).
Recipes should be related with the Cusine. What I want is when I create a post for a recipe, to directly take the selections for courses, cusine and country.

I have created the two main taxonomies (Courses and Country) but I am not sure how to continue from here. How can I create a subtaxonomy and relate two subtaxonomies?

Thank you

Comment: Subtaxonomies aren't a thing in WordPress, that's not how taxonomies work, are you referring instead to parent/child terms within a single taxonomy? WordPress does not have any concept of inter-relating for taxonomies themselves in the way that you describe.

Comment: What is it the problem that sub-taxonomies would have solved for you? If you ask about what you're trying to implement then perhaps somebody can write an answer that tells you how to do it, rather than having to explain why sub-taxonomies do not exist

Comment: Ok, I see. So there's no way to connect a term with two taxonomies?

Comment: terms exist in a taxonomy, a taxonomy can have many terms, a term can be in only 1 taxonomy. Taxonomies are ways of grouping things, terms are the groups. E.g. A colour taxonomy, with red/blue/green terms. Any hierarchy exists inside the taxonomy with child/parent terms, e.g. if I created a _pale red_ term and said it was a sub-group of _red_, or if I had a location taxonomy with an _Asia_ term, and a _Bangladesh_ child-term. I'm not sure what you're trying to build so I don't know what to suggest, if you can share more information about your original problem

Comment: Logically though, it does not make sense to have a term that exists in 2 taxonomies, as that means those 2 taxonomies are the same thing, and should be 1 taxonomy. If you're trying to implement filter overlaps or intersections then you do not need to "connect" the taxonomies. It's perfectly fine to request all posts that have a term in the X taxonomy, and a term in the Y taxonomy, you don't need to connect X and Y to do that

Comment: I've re-read your question and I think I understand the fundamental mistake. Recipes should not be a taxonomy, it should be a custom post type, or it should be eliminated as your posts are already the recipes

Comment: What I want is recipe to directly take the selected terms from both (parent?) taxonomies. Wouldn;t be possible to have the recipe as a related field instead of term? And connect the cusine (term) with the recipe? 

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a parent taxonomy, that's not how taxonomies work. Can you describe what you're trying to build in human user/business terms rather  than technical terms?

Comment: Well, I want to have a post about one recipe. This recipe should belong to one Course. I also want this recipe to be connected/related to one cusine. The cusine should also belong to one country. So when I create the post and select the recipe from a list of recipes, I want to inherit the course (as parent category maybe) and the selected cusine. Somehow I want the recipe to be included in two lists (one of the courses and one of the country > cusine)

Comment: So you want a list of recipes filtered by country and cuisine. Just create a single taxonomy named `cuisine`, create terms for every country, and child terms for those countries cuisines. The recipe taxonomy makes no sense, get rid of it, your posts are the recipes. If your site only has recipes the you can use categorys instead of a custom taxonomy. After all _"Italian"_ cuisine is a type of cuisine, as are the various cuisines that come from Italy

Comment: I have this structure: 
Course >Recipe and Country >Cusine. When I create a new post about a recipe (let's say RecA), this RecA should be also connected to a cusine (let;s say cusA). So the post has already prefilled the parent categories from RecA (the course) and from the cusine (the country). Is there any way to make this kind of connection with RecA and cusA? Maybe if there are not terms and there related fields or something?